# Is it viable to encrypt a 'bitlocked' drive again?

Tags: disk-encryption, bitlocker, veracrypt

If one had an encrypted drive using Bitlocker, is it worth it to encrypt that drive again using another tool like VeraCrypt? Does this provide an extra layer of protection?

**Not a duplicate of a question which deals with a more generalised point of view.**

Answer (score 2):

Not really unless you are attempting to prevent people that have the bitlocker decryption key from accessing the drive, presuming you can make that work at all.

Answer (score 1):

You are not adding any security. The difficulty on obtaining two passwords is not double of the work of getting one password. If someone manages to compromise one password, you can assume they can compromise two or three.

If you have a keylogger installed, it will get whatever decryption passwords you have, no matter how many. In this case, encrypting it two or ten times adds nothing.

If you are targeted by a government agency, you may have to hand off the keys, so having an extra layer does not improve anything.

And if you somehow loses one password, you lose the entire drive. By considering security as the called *CIA principles* (**C**onfidentiality, **I**ntegrity, **A**vailability), the more layers you add, the less security you have - because of the decreased availability potential.

Comment: Actually it doesn't decrease availability necessarily.   Use of the TPM chip in the machine means that the password  is for recovery purposes.  So you'd only need the veracrypt password.